# jFlip jQuery plugin - How to load a curly tab when page loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

With the [jFlip jQuery plugin](http://www.jquery.info/spip.php?article78), is there a way to load a curly tab when the page loads?

**UPDATE 5/21/2013 6:08 PM**

Still stuck.  If we are able to use

```
c.mousemove(function(e) {.....}
```

with this plugin, how come the console log doesn't load for...

```
c.on('load',function(e) {
       console.log('canvas has loaded');
});
```

or this...

```
  c.bind("load",function(e){
      console.log('canvas loaded');
    });
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the quick and easy solution to have the curly tab initially show itself folding when the actual slider loads onto your page. Simply append the following two lines code...

```
startDate = new Date().getTime();
animationTimer = window.setInterval(cornerCurlIn,10);
```

...**within** the var Flip = function(...){}

Once the user scrolls their mouse into the image area, everything will act as it was originally meant to be.  By going with this approach you are not reinventing the wheel or fixing the complexity of this code.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to copy the on 'mouseenter' event listener here on line #136
http://www.jquery.info/scripts/jFlip/jquery.jflip-0.4.js

then add a 'onload' event listener which calls the same functionality for the curl to happen

http://pastebin.com/index/X2PJSMsW

Comment: hmm..I agree with your thought process, but for some reason it doesn;t work.  the corner flapper doesn't show on load....